# Reading comment lines correctly in an input file using Fortran 90

Tags: file-io, comments, fortran, gfortran

It is my understanding that Fortran, when reading data from file, will skip lines starting with and asterisk (*) assuming that they are a comment.  Well, I seem to be having a problem with achieving this behavior with a very simple program I created.  This is my simple Fortran program:

```
  1       program test
  2 
  3       integer dat1
  4 
  5       open(unit=1,file="file.inp")
  6 
  7       read(1,*) dat1
  8 
  9 
 10       end program test
```

This is "file.inp":

```
  1 *Hello
  2 1
```

I built my simple program with

```
gfortran -g -o test test.f90
```

When I run, I get the error:

```
At line 7 of file test.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'file.inp')
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input
```

When I run the input file with the comment line deleted, i.e.:

```
1 1
```

The code runs fine.  So it seems to be a problem with Fortran correctly interpreting that comment line.  It must be something exceedingly simple I'm missing here, but I can't turn up anything on google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fortran doesn't automatically skip comments lines in input files.  You can do this easily enough by first reading the line into a string, checking the first character for your comment symbol or search the string for that symbol, then if the line is not a comment, doing an "internal read" of the string to obtain the numeric value.

Something like:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

character (len=200) :: line
integer :: dat1, RetCode

read_loop: do
   read (1, '(A)', isostat=RetCode)  line
    if ( RetCode == iostat_end)  exit ReadLoop
    if ( RetCode /= 0 ) then
      ... read error
      exit read_loop
    end if
    if ( index (line, "*") /= 0 )  cycle read_loop
    read (line, *) dat1
end do read_loop
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out, actually, and was coming back to post my solution.  However, your code is a bit smarter than the solution I came up with (I was using the "end=" option for my read statement).  One thing I don't understand, though, is what's the need for the use of "iso_fortran_env"?  Sorry, I've written some big  Fortran programs and get them working, but I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to intrinsic modules and what they bring to the table.

Comment: Among other things, iso_fortran_env provides the value "isostat_end" to test whether a non-zero return code is end-of-file.  This allows the use of the "exit" construct instead of statement labels, as with "end=LineNumber".

Answer (score 0):

Fortran does not ignore anything by default, unless you are using namelists and in that case comments start with an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

I found the use of the [backspace](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfpro78help/F95ARBACKSPACEStmt.htm) statement to be a lot more intuitive than the proposed solutions. The following subroutine skips the line when a comment character, "#" is encountered at the beginning of the line.

```
subroutine skip_comments(fileUnit)
  integer, intent(in) :: fileUnit
  character(len=1) :: firstChar

  firstChar = '#'
  do while (firstChar .eq. '#')
    read(fileUnit, '(A)') firstChar
  enddo
  backspace(fileUnit)

end subroutine skip_comments
```

This subroutine may be used in programs before the `read` statement like so:

```
open(unit=10, file=filename)
call skip_comments(10)
read(10, *) a, b, c
call skip_comments(10)
read(10, *) d, e
close(10)
```

Limitations for the above implementation:

1. It will not work if the comment is placed *between* the values of a variable spanning multiple lines, say an array.
2. It is very inefficient for large input files since the entire file is re-read from the beginning till the previous character when the backspace statement is encountered.
3. Can only be used for `sequential` access files, i.e. typical ASCII text files. Files opened with the `direct` or `append` access types will not work.

However, I find it a perfect fit for short files used for providing user-parameters.

Comment: And let's not forget the charming "Backspacing over records written using list-directed or namelist formatting is prohibited."