# Labeled-break/continue in C# or Fortran 95 loops?

Tags: c#, fortran, break, continue

I've been tasked in a homework assignment with converting a loop in C# into Fortran 95.

```
outerLoop:
  for(row = 0; row < numRows; rows++){
    for(col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
      if(mat[row][col] == 0)
        continue outerLoop;
      sum += mat[row][col];
    }
  }
```

As some of you can see, this looks similar to the exit statement label specification used in Java and Perl, which, to my understanding, are used to break out of loops that have nested loops or '*if*' statements rather than just a single loop/statement.  I'm still new to this feature in Java, so I'm not sure if it exists anywhere else, specifically in C# and Fortran 95.

I've looked around on Google, but I haven't found anything for it.  I have a bad time formulating search terms to use on Google, so that factors into it, as well.

Please note: I'm not looking for a handout answer; I'm just looking for where to find the answer myself.

Thank you for taking time out to read this post.

Comment: I think you're looking for `goto`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

Comment: I don't know what `continue outerLoop` does exactly, but if you place a `break` in that place, it will break the inner loop and allow the outer loop to continue.

Comment: You really want to read about jump statements in C#- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d96yfwee.aspx

Comment: The question *is unclear*. Is it about converting the (*invalid*) C# to Fortran or if the (*Java?*) code has a corresponding direct C# counterpart? See "...converting a loop *in* C# into Fortran 95."

Comment: Given the likely outcome of this snippet, the Fortran keyword is probably HALT_AND_CATCH_FIRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe such a `break x` feature is not supported in C#. You would need to break out of the nested loops manually using flags.

```
bool stop = false;
for (row = 0; row < numRows; rows++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
    {
        if (mat[row][col] == 0)
        {
            stop = true;
            break;
        }

        sum += mat[row][col];
    }

    if (stop)
        break;
}
```

Simpler alternatives include the `goto` statement (which is widely frowned upon); and encapsulating your loop within a dedicated method, in which case, you could just `return` when you want to stop iterating.

Comment: After looking at the jump statement for C#, I've come to the conclusion that 1) the "continue to label" for C# does not exist, and 2) my teacher definitely gave us the wrong set of instructions/code for the problem, which ultimately results in an incorrect error.

Comment: @user1170036: From your example, I assume your teacher was referring to the [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) statement, which is supported in C#, but strongly discouraged from use – especially in academic settings – since it goes against the principles of [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming).

Comment: How is `break` different from `goto`? That is, why would `break foo` be fine, but `goto foo` would be discouraged?

Comment: `break foo` is not allowed in C# (or any other language than I know of). By `break x`, I was referring to the syntax in some languages (such as PHP) which allows the specification of “an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of” – see [PHP: break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

Answer (score 3):

For examples of loop-control constructs in Fortran 95, see my example code in the previous Fortran question, which has example uses of "cycle" and "exit": [Reading comment lines correctly in an input file using Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259712/reading-comment-lines-correctly-in-an-input-file-using-fortran-90), .

Comment: While I believe goto has a place, Naming loops is way better than using goto in this context.  +1