# Read an input with comments in FORTRAN 77

Tags: input, comments, fortran

I have an simple input file with comments (lines starting with #) in it. Sample data looks like:

```
#NDIM
 1
#NX   NY   NZ
 3001 1    1
#I_RXN
 2
```

I would like to tell the code that every time I encounter the character # at the start of the line to skip that line and to move on to the next line. I have to do this in FORTRAN 77.

Comment: What have you got so far ?  We're here to help.  We're not here to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the lines into a string then test whether the first character is "#".   If not, use an "internal read" to read the numerical values from the string.   There have been previous answers about this technique, e.g., [Reading comment lines correctly in an input file using Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259712/reading-comment-lines-correctly-in-an-input-file-using-fortran-90)

Comment: +1 Parsing the input string is ussually the way to go. Or using namelists, they allow comments.