# Fortran randomely writing data in file

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

How to write a text or dat file in FORTRAN like a 2D array of integers and each time to enter a value, if in any row there is no value just insert in the start but if some values exists insert to the end of values. This insertion of values can be random, i.e. may be line number 100 first then 80 then 101 then 2. The number of entries in each line is also different. 
I also need to use this file at the end but I think that will be easy as need line by line information.

***Edit (what he ment possibly) ::*** How to write a text file in Fortran, like a 2D array of integers, each time adding one value? If there is an empty row with no values, insert one at the beginning of a row, but if there are already some values in that row, append the new value to the end of the row.

*Have no idea what he was getting at with those random values and line numbers.*

Comment: Your problem statement is hard to understand.  Try describing what you want to do in pseudocode.  Then a FORTRAN user can probably fill you in on some of the details of IO statements.  Also, it would be helpful to specify just one dialect.  You've tagged your post with 3 different ones.

Comment: Tried to make some sense of it, but an additional clarification would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make decisions based on the input, read the line into a string.   Then examine the contents of the string and decide which case of input.   If you have numbers that you want to read, use an "internal read" to read them from the string.   This  question has a code example: [Reading comment lines correctly in an input file using Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259712/reading-comment-lines-correctly-in-an-input-file-using-fortran-90)