# Fortran Program will compile but not run for large values of N (around >4500)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have recently made a program for my undergrad research project, designed to calculate the mean of a large number of data columns. Everything compiles and runs fine when I use low numbers for N, but for large numbers of N (and this is necessary, given the true N value I need is around 40000, representing 40000 columns of data to read and operate on,) the program compiles with gfortran with no errors, but the program created does not produce an output. I double click, run as admin, etc etc, but the program just does nothing when I open it. Here is my code:

```
program mean_analysis
    implicit none
    
    integer i
    integer N
    double precision a, b, c, d, e
    double precision sumb
    double precision sumc
    double precision sumd
    double precision suma
    double precision sume
            
    
    
    
    sumb = 0
    sumc = 0
    sumd = 0
    suma = 0
    sume = 0
    
    N=40009
    
    open(unit = 5, file="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
    read(5, *) 
        do i = 1, N 
            read(5,*) a, b, c, d, e
            suma = suma+a
            sumb = sumb+b
            sumc = sumc+c
            sumd = sumd+d
            sume = sume+e 
        end do
    close(5)
    
    open(unit = 8, file="outputanalysis2.dat")
        do i = 1, 1
            write(8,*) suma/N, sumb/N, sumc/N, sumd/N, sume/N
        end do
    close(8)
    
    end program
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what to change to make it work. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated - I've been stuck on this for quite some time. Thanks!

I ran for N<1000 , and everything works. Beyond N>4000, it compiles but the program created does not run/create an output file like expected.

Comment: You say that it doesn't run as you expect: how does it run?

Comment: When I say it doesn't run as expected - I mean that if I put a large value for N, compile the code and run the created executable, nothing happens (it should create an output file with the average values I want. I should note that the last do loop should go from i to 1. I changed it to N because I wanted to see how far the program was going. I have just fixed that - my apologies. Would it help to attach the file I am getting my data from?

Comment: it looks like your program read the N lines from your input and then calculate the mean and write in out, probably it is failing somewhere in reading the inputs. Does your input file has that many lines ? print each line that you are reading and see where is the problem that it stops.

Comment: To do this, could I just replace the second do loop with a write(8,*) a, b, c, d, e line? @amirhm

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the suggestion @High Performance Mark . I am still very new to fortran so I don't quite understand a lot yet.

Comment: So it seems that any N past N=4000, the program created does not create an output file like it should.

Comment: @GarrettLeigh Have you tried N=4001 ? If it fails with that, then is there something different in the data file at that line?

Comment: I just figured it out - there is a comment with a hashtag in front of it around line 4000. Is there a good way to tell the program to ignore any lines starting with a hashtag?

Comment: @GarrettLeigh Does [Reading comment lines correctly in an input file using Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259712/reading-comment-lines-correctly-in-an-input-file-using-fortran-90) solve the problem for you?

Comment: read(5,*) seems dangerous because I think 5 should be reserved for standard input, although that is machine dependent.

Comment: @GarrettLeigh Note that what you're calling columns are actually rows in the file.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You are correct.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, for that, is it easily translatable to Fortran 77?

Comment: @GarrettLeigh Now that you have found that the problem is due to the input, perhaps you could write the whole program using Fortran 90.

Comment: Unfortunately, my professor requires me to use Fortran 77. I'm reading into using iostat but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to use it (to skip over  any lines beginning with #)

Comment: *my professor requires me to use Fortran 77* Your professor is a **** and if you are paying for your education you are being cheated.  Unless, that is, your question has come through a wormhole from the 1980s ...

Comment: Haha! It is a bit frustrating, limiting ourselves to the prospects of an old version of a programming language.

Comment: Please describe _how_ the program isn't working as expected.

Comment: @JAlex I have explained previously, but I need to find a way to skip/not read/ignore any line beginning with # in fortran 77. If I don't, the program won't execute after the 4000th line because of a comment there.

Comment: @GarrettLeigh - Please [edit] the question and add the relevant details then. The comments isn't the place to leave crucial information needed to answer the question.

Comment: If you need to write Fortran 77 code then I'm afraid you have a lot of rewriting to do. Even leaving aside the lower case letters, you can't call your program `mean_analysis`, you can't use `implicit none` or `end do` and you need to make all your lines (even those like the third) 72 characters wide. If you really do need to write F77 code (you don't) then you can easily ignore lines beginning with `#` in a reasonably similar way to the "F90" answers

Comment: Why the hell would a professor require using F77 ??

Comment: VTC - The question asked is not the question the asker wants answered.  That seems to be *How to skip comment lines in a data file?*. Further, if the answer is to be written in FORTRAN 77, it's not unreasonable for us to expect the proto-program to be written in FORTRAN 77.

Comment: You should **not** run your code by double clicking. You have to run it from the command line to see any error messages. Go to cmd.exe or Powershell and run your code from there. Also, you should compile it with all debugging options that your compilers offers. E.g. `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`. I recommend to do the compilation in the command line as well.

Comment: Later update of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527313/how-to-successfully-skip-lines-beginning-with-reading-from-an-external-file/