# How to skip lines beginning with # when reading an external file

Tags: fortran

I am having trouble with my code. My goal is to calculate the average of 5 different columns of data. Problem is, in the data file every 4000 lines or so there is a comment beginning with #. I need to read each of these lines into a character string, so that my code will not read them as numbers to be added. I am doing this as a research project for my university and was instructed to use Fortran 77 without arrays. Here is my code:

```
    program mean_analysis
    implicit none
    
    integer i
    integer N
    double precision a, b, c, d, e
    double precision sumb
    double precision sumc
    double precision sumd
    double precision suma
    double precision sume
    character(100) event

    sumb = 0
    sumc = 0
    sumd = 0
    suma = 0
    sume = 0
    
    N=40010
    
    open(unit = 7, file="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
        
        do i=1, 1
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=4002, 4002
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=8003, 8003
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=12004, 12004
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=16005, 16005
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=20006, 20006
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=24007, 24007
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=28008, 28008
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=32009, 32009
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
        do i=36010, 36010
        read(7,'(A)') event
        end do
                    
        do i=1, N 
        
            read(7,*) a, b, c, d, e 
            write(7, *) event
            suma = suma+a
            sumb = sumb+b
            sumc = sumc+c
            sumd = sumd+d
            sume = sume+e
            
                
        end do
        
        
    close(7)
    
    open(unit = 8, file="outputanalysis.dat")
            write(8,*) suma/N, sumb/N, sumc/N, sumd/N, sume/N
    close(8)
    
    end program
```

The issue is when I run this code, there is a runtime error. The code still thinks that each event (at the lines provided) is a number and attempts to add it into the sum for each column
(`Bad real number in item 1 of list input`) [there is a # on the first line in the data file]). I want the program to essentially ignore each row beginning with a #.

Can someone fill me in on what I'm doing wrong, or suggestions on what to include? I am new to Fortran, so anything too advanced might go over my head.

I tried putting each "event" (rows beginning with #) into a character string so that they would not be read as a number. The program still thinks they are numbers to be added.

Comment: The first several do-loops do not do what you probably want.  The first 10 or so simply read the first 10 lines of the file.  What you want to do is use an internal read to parse the file.

Comment: You really ought to delete the earlier version of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462993/fortran-program-will-compile-but-not-run-for-large-values-of-n-around-4500 That is now just tumbleweed in the streets of SO.

Comment: Still with the one trip loops `do i=12004, 12004` (passim)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Fortran's internal read capability.  First, read a line from the file, then determine if it is a comment or needs to be parsed for values.  Here's a quick hack.  You should probably include error handling if a read fails.

```
    program mean_analysis

    implicit none

    integer i, n
    double precision a(5), s(5)
    character(100) event

    s = 0
    n = 0

    open(unit = 7, file="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
    do
       read(7,'(A)',end=10) event
       event = adjustl(event)

       if (event(1:1) == '#') cycle  ! Skip comment lines

       read(event,*) a
       s = s + a
       n = n + 1
    end do

    10 close(7)

    open(unit = 8, file="outputanalysis.dat")
    write(8,*) s / n
    close(8)

    end program
```

Edited:  Seems you should make an appointment with the department chair or dean or provost.  Forcing you to use a 46 year old dialect of a language is not preparing you for the future.  If your prof insists on F77, then at least have some fun (although I doubt he'll look at the code).

```
      INTEGER I, N
      DOUBLE PRECISION A,B,C,D,E,SA,SB,SC,SD,SE
      DATA SA,SB,SC,SD,SE,N/5*0,0/
      COMMON SA, A
      OPEN(UNIT=7,FILE="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
1000  READ(7,*,ERR=1000,END=100) A,B,C,D,E
      CALL SA AND A
      SB=S  B + B
      S  C                    =SC                   + C
      SD =D + S      D
      CALLADDE(S     E,                          E)
      N = N + 1 
      GOTO 1000
1 0 0 CONTINUE
      CLOSE(7)
      OPEN(UNIT=8,FILE="outputanalysis.dat")
      WRITE(8,*) SA/N, S B/N, S  C / N, SD/    N, SE/N
      CLOSE(8)
      END
      SUBROUTINE ADD E(S,                                             X)
      DOUBLEPRECISION S,X
      DOUBLE                                             PRECISION C,T,Y
      DATA C /0/
      Y = X - C
      T = S + Y
      C = (T - S) - Y
      S = T
      END
      SUBROUTINE SA AND A
      DOUBLE PRECISION SS,TT
      COMMON SS,TT
      SS = SS + TT
      END
```

Comment: My deepest apologies - I should have mentioned that my professor instructed me to not include arrays and to use Fortran 77. I assume there are arrays at work in that program? Thank you very much for your input and help.

Comment: The code you present in the question is not Fortran 77 for a number of reasons. Nobody should be using Fortran 77, and nobody should have been using Fortran 77 since roughly the start of this millennium. You also have an array in your original program. That said internal I/O has been in standard Fortran since at least Fortran 77.

Comment: Yes, it is using array notation.  You can go back to individual variables with the obvious changes.  A question you should ask yourself, "is how much am I paying into tuition to learn a programming language, Fortran 77, that has been superseded by Fortran 90, 95, 2003, 2008, 2018, and in a month or so Fortran 2023?"

Comment: I know I know. Fortunately, this research project is simply for 3 credit hours of electives I need to graduate. Everything else I am taking and doing at my university is more related to my actual field of interest than this is. I have felt from the start, though, that we should not be restricting ourselves to F77. I thought it was archaic, and that we are limiting what we can do by sticking to such an old version.

Comment: I repeat - the code you present at the beginning is **not**  Fortran77. If this is what the Professor is telling you is Fortran77 then he/she does not know what he/she is talking about.

Comment: @steve `IMPLICITDOUBLEPRECISION(A-H,O-Z)`? If that is the syntax, I really can't, and don't want to, remember. And if it were me I would remove all the unnecessary spaces. Oh - and you need to change "  to '

Comment: Forcing a student to strictly use F77 syntax from scratch looks like a joke or some kind of hazing... If not a joke, this professor should be dismissed asap...

Comment: @IanBush. It took only a few minutes to write the free-form source code version with array syntax.  I had to refer to F2018 and F77 standards to ensure I got the syntax right in the second version.  Took much longer to write.   I had `CALL ADD SA AND A`, then realized that subroutine name was too long.  Ah, memories.

Comment: @steve Indeed. People forget how primitive F77 was, and error prone when compared to modern Fortran. Teaching is doing the students a complete disservice.

Comment: I am not sure i would call using it a joke.
It is possible that someone in the sciences would run across F77 style, and the professor is not likely a jokester.

Comment: Sure, one can run across Fortran 77 code or Fortran 66 code on the internet (see Netlib).  It is a joke, if not malpractice, to force students learning Fortran in 2023 to write new code in a 46+ year dialect that has been superseded by 6 revisions to the Fortran standard.

Comment: @steve When trying to use your solution, I get a compiling error:help.f:24:9:

   24 |                 10 close(7)
      |                       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
help.f:14:26:

   14 |                 read(7,'(A)',end=10) event
      |                                        1
Error: END tag label 10 at (1) not defined

How do I go about resolving these issues? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you're using gfortran, a file ending with the extension `.f` is assumed to be fixed-form source code.  The first program with the `10 close(7)` statement is written in free-form source.  Rename the file to `help.f90`, which gfortran recognizes as free form.  There is also a gfortran option, but I don't remember it at the moment.